# Passing objc block to function

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

have been strugling with this over 2 days, I am not very skilled in C. So, have an objc function mapped to C function with the following syntax

```
extern int32_t createWallet(void (*fn)(int32_t handle, int32_t errCode)
```

but dont know how to pass a block like function. Have been trying to pass

```
void (^ createWalletCallback)(int32_t t, int32_t e) = NULL;
createWalletCallback = ^void(int32_t t, int32_t e){
    /// some code here
}
```

but no success. Could you pls at least point me what to change? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to wrap an ObjectiveC block into function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006685/is-there-a-way-to-wrap-an-objectivec-block-into-function-pointer)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of [Is there a way to wrap an ObjectiveC block into function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006685/is-there-a-way-to-wrap-an-objectivec-block-into-function-pointer), where the advice is "don't do it".

Instead, can you not use a plain C function pointer?  Define a function

```
void createWalletCallback(int32_t t, int32_t e) {
    // some code here, maybe referencing global variables
    // (including a semaphore, if other code needs to wait on the response)
}
```

and then just call

```
createWallet(&createWalletCallback);
```

Comment: well, yes, could be an option to declare then some static fields in source file. problem is that there are like 5-6 callbacks to accomplish one unit of work, therefore i was looking to "bundle" the functions like lambdas (coming from .net world)

Comment: the difficulty here is that blocks are fully-fledged objective-c objects.  Objective-C is a layer above the C language, with its own runtime.  C function pointers are just C function pointers; they don't know about the object properties, which - when you have a block - are used to capture the variables you would no doubt want to access within the block.  (Hope that makes sense!)