# Assigning to 'void (*)(int, const char *, int)' from incompatible type 'void (^__strong)(int, const char *, int)'

Tags: objective-c

I am not too familiar with Objective-C, so this is probably a very obvious mistake.

`Assigning to 'void (*)(int, const char *, int)' from incompatible type 'void (^__strong)(int, const char *, int)'`

I am encountering the error above when making this assignment

```
log_cfg.cb = callback;
```

This is the definition of `callback`

```
void (^callback)(int, const char*, int) = ^(int level, const char* data, int len) {

    ...

};
```

Comment: What does the property definition of log_cfg.cb look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that `log_cfg.cb` expects a function pointer, but you hand in a block. A block is not a function pointer, and you cannot easily mix both (other than in swift, where it's much easier).

If you don't need value capturing, you could write your block code in a (global?) function and hand in that function pointer. Or check [Is there a way to wrap an ObjectiveC block into function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006685/is-there-a-way-to-wrap-an-objectivec-block-into-function-pointer)

Comment: Thank you, this got me going in the right direction!